# How to export multiple photoshop projects at once?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, batch-processing, jpg, crop

Sometimes I get a lot of PDF documents of multiple scanned photos from costumers and I need to crop them, straighten them and export them as JPG.

Now, It's really time consuming doing it manualy. I found a way to crop and straighten them automaticly through photoshop, but not a way to batch export them.

So I need a way to:

1. Batch export nultiple photoshop photos.
2. Crop, straighten and export multiple PDF scanned photos through Photoshop.
3. Find a freeware software to do the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **Droplet** to perform batch actions with the drop of a file or files.

Merely set up an action while you walk through the steps for a single image.

- New Action folder
- New Action
- Start recording
- Open file
- Perform all steps
- Save
- Close
- Stop Recording

Save the action folder

Choose `File > Automate > Create Droplet`

Choose the action set you saved on the left, and then set up destination options on the right.

[image]

When you get new files, you can **merely drop them onto the droplet** and the action steps will be performed on each image.

---

I have a client that sends me RGB chart files that need to be reduced to greyscale and then adjusted for size. I set up an action t perform the necessary steps on one of the images....

[image]

Then I created a **droplet** from that action.

When new images come in (10 at a time), I merely drop all the images onto a droplet, let Photoshop do it's thing for a couple minutes.. and they are all ready for use.

Here's another action I used to create a **droplet** which sharpens and auto-color corrects another client's screenshot files they send me. (They always need the same C boost and M drop).

[image]

---

<sub>Caveat: I'm assuming droplets are OS agnostic. I've never used Windows. So, don't shoot me if there's no Droplet option. I have a difficult time imagining there isn't though.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Use Photoshop's built-in batch and action scripts. You can set a folder that Photoshop will use to open documents. Then perform the necessary tasks to crop, straighten, and save as. Record that as an new Action by doing Window>Actions and then set up your batch by doing File>Automate>Batch.